# Filtering by date in graphql

Tags: api, filter, graphql

I'm brand new to graphql and I'm just trying to construct a simple query that will filter for results with a plannedExpirationDate value after a certain datetime. How do I write that filter?

```
{
  loans (filters: {gender: male, status:funded, country: ["KE", "US"]}, sortBy: newest, limit: 2) {
    totalCount
    values {
      name
      status
      loanAmount
      image {
        url(presetSize: small)
      }
      activity {
        name
      }
      plannedExpirationDate
      location {
        country {
          isoCode
          name
        }
      }
      lenders (limit: 100) {
        totalCount
      }
      ... on LoanPartner {
        partnerName
      }
      ... on LoanDirect {
        trusteeName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, GraphQL is a syntax for interacting with an API. From your question, it sounds like you are attempting to interact with someone else's GraphQL API. How to implement a filter is not part of the GraphQL standard (the GraphQL standard describes how to pass arguments, but not what to do with those arguments after they are received). You need to ask the owner of a particular API the proper way to filter a particular query. In addition to any documentation they have, you can try performing an [introspection query](http://graphql.org/learn/introspection/) to find out more about the API's schema.